# is there any way to increase spawn rate of MinSpareServers in apache prefork

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, performance, tuning

My server faces huge traffic only for short duration every day. And I don't want to waste my resource by running high amount of MaxSpareServers throughout the day.
So, I would like to know is there any way to increase the spawn rate by the exponential of 100s... means increase rate should be 100,200,400,800...

My configuration :

[image]

Comment: can you instead stick a reverse proxy (squid, varnish, ...) in front of the server? or go with some content delivery network?

Comment: @thrig , currently not having those options...